# Failed to process input

Tags: powershell, iis

```
$physicalPath = 'C:\Projects\Foo'

& cmd /c C:\windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd set vdir 'Default Web Site/' -physicalPath:$physicalPath
```

> Error: "Failed to process input: The Parameter 'C:\Projects\Foo' must
>   begin with a \ or -"

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$physicalPath = 'C:\Projects\Foo'
$defaultsite = 'Default Web Site/'

start-process cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/c C:\windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd set vdir $defaultsite /physicalPath:$physicalPath"
```

I'm not sure where you are getting your physicalpath parameter from as you aren't really using a command to get a parameter set, this might help you.